# How to use highchart 3d with angular 5?

Tags: angular, charts, highcharts

I am just adding to app.module.ts

```
import { ChartModule } from 'angular-highcharts';
```

and to import

```
ChartModule
```

Now i want to use highchart-3d
how can i do that?
Can i customize the chart to make it something like morris.js donut chart?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check [add-highcharts-modules](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-highcharts#add-highcharts-modules) from npm packages.

> Any other modules like highcharts-3d, highcharts-exporintg and etc. can be also added in @NgModule after main chart module

```
...
@NgModule({
    ...
    imports: [
      BrowserModule, 
      ChartModule.forRoot(
        require('highcharts'),
+       require('highcharts/highchart-3d'),
+       require('highcharts/modules/exporting')
      ],
})
```

Check http://plnkr.co/edit/sz6OfccvAetQcBX8KFXy?p=preview .

If you are facing problem then add live example

Comment: Hi, when I did this to build for production, this error came out: ERROR in Error during template compile of 'AppModule'
  Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'ChartModule' was called.

Answer (score 2):

This approach also works :

```
import * as highcharts3d from 'highcharts/highcharts-3d';
export function highchartsFactory() {
    const hc = require('highcharts/highstock');
    highcharts3d(hc);
    return hc;
}

@NgModule({
imports: [
  ChartModule
],
providers: [
{
  provide: HighchartsStatic,
  useFactory: highchartsFactory //this will take care of inlcuding highcharts 3d module
}
]
});
```

For more details : https://github.com/gevgeny/angular2-highcharts/issues/193

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import highcharts3D from 'highcharts/highcharts-3d.src';
highcharts3D(Highcharts);
```

[Refer](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/angular_highcharts/angular_highcharts_3d_pie.htm)

Comment: `highcharts3D(Highcharts);` this is throwing error in angular cli 9.1.4